# Try Except While with user input

Tags: python, exception, while-loop, try-catch

Below is a sample of my problem. I have a script that is trying to access an excel file. It works fine, but if the file is currently open, I would get a permission denied error. I would typically close the file and run the script again, but I want to be able to close the program and just enter a keystroke for example 'y', to indicate the file is closed and to try again. My issue now is when I enter any value, it would still continue trying to run and if fails a second time it would exit the script. Any ideas?

```
input_yes = 'y'
answer = {}
try:
    finalSheet('my file.xlsx')
except:
    while answer != str(input_yes):
         answer = input('Please confirm that (my file.xlsx) is closed and enter y: ')
         finalSheet('my file.xlsx')
         continue
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
input_yes = 'y'
while True:
    try:
        finalSheet('my file.xlsx')
        break #If reading the file succeeded, it will leave the outer loop
    except:
        while True:
            answer = input('Please confirm that (my file.xlsx) is closed and enter y: ')
            if answer == input_yes:
                break #If the answer is 'y', it will leave the inner loop, and try to read the file. Otherwise, it will continue to ask for readiness
```

Comment: I haven't been able to try it, since the first comment was exactly when I needed, but if anyone were to experienced this in the future, I hope they would try it out.

Comment: @Sigmas In the answer you used, if the user presses anything but 'y', it will be aborted, while in my code it will wait until the user does press 'y', which is what I understood from the question. But if you actually prefer his method, no problem.

Comment: I tried yours, it works just as well. I didn't get to try it before since @Yotamz script works as well. I modified it a little, but both are great. Never meant to doubt you!

Answer (score 0):

I can't really program in python, but in most languages the exception handling block is not considered to be part of the `try` block, otherwise you wouldn't be able to rethrow the exception from it.

You need to change the code so the whole thing is inside a loop.

```
success = False

while not success:
    try:
        finalSheet('my file.xlsx')
        success = True
    except:
        # We actually don't care what the answer is. You could bail if the 
        # answer is no I guess
        answer = input('Please confirm that (my file.xlsx) is closed and enter y: ')
```

Apologies for any mistakes in the above, my Python is not great.

Comment: It's no problem, I'm learning too, the first comment was exactly what I needed, but thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

```
try:
    while True:
        try:
            finalSheet('my file.xlsx')
            print('Success')
            break
        except:
            if not input('Please confirm that (my file.xlsx) is closed and enter y: ') == str(input_yes):
                raise KeyboardInterrupt #or any other exception
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('Cancelled by user')
    return
```

You want to put the entire block inside a "try".
The loop will break if the operation succeeded, skipping the outer "except" block.

If there is an exception (i.e. file is locked) and the user answers "y" then the loop continues.

If the file is locked and the user answers !"y" then a new exception is raised, exiting the loop into the last "except" block.

Comment: I do not want to user to cancel, I want the script to stay on, and wait until the file is closed.